# Radio button with additional text field javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 radio buttons for:

- Allowance
- Tuition
- School

If I click the Radio Button for Allowance, it will open the `ul` list .

Now, the Radio Button for Allowance should be closed after clicking the Radio Button for Tuition

When I click the Radio Button for "Not full Tuition", I am supposed to type in the text field for Money but it closes on its on.

I want to prevent it from closing after clicking "Not Full Tuition Fee" so I can type a value in the Money textfield.

It will also just close if I click the Radio Button for School.

How can I get this to work?

```js
function Allowance(select) {
  if (select.value == 'Allowance') {
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Tuition(select) {
  if (select.value == 'Tuition Fee') {
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Supply(select) {
  if (select.value == 'School Supply') {
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Not_Full(select) {
  if (select.value == 'Not Full') {
    document.getElementById('Not_Full').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Not_Full').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="Allowance" id="test" onchange="Allowance(this)"> Allowance<br>
<div id="allowance" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Food Allowance</li>
    <li>Transportation Allowance</li>
  </ul>
  <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="Tuition Fee" id="test" onchange="Tuition(this)"> Tution<br>
<div id="tuition_fee" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Tuition Fee</li>
    <input type="radio" name="test1" value="Full"> Full Tuition Fee<br>
    <input type="radio" name="test1" value="Not Full" id="test" onchange="Not_Full(this)"> Not Full Tuition Fee<br>
  </ul>
  <div id="Not_Full" style="display: none;">
    <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>

</div>
<input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="School Supply" id="test" onchange="Supply(this)"> School
<div id="school_supply" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Books</li>
    <li>Uniform</li>
  </ul>
  <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for? I didn't understand the *I want to prevent it from closing after clicking "Not Full Tuition Fee" so I can type a value in the Money textfield.* Cause even if you do select another radio button and come back, the value for the money field will still be there!!
Correct me if my understanding is wrong

```js
function reset() {
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
}

function Allowance(select) {
  reset();
  if (select.value == 'Allowance') {
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('allowance').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Tuition(select) {
  reset();
  if (select.value == 'Tuition Fee') {
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('tuition_fee').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Supply(select) {
  reset();
  if (select.value == 'School Supply') {
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('school_supply').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function Not_Full(select) {
  if (select.value == 'Not Full') {
    document.getElementById('Not_Full').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Not_Full').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="Allowance" id="test" onchange="Allowance(this)"> Allowance<br>
<div id="allowance" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Food Allowance</li>
    <li>Transportation Allowance</li>
  </ul>
  <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="Tuition Fee" id="test" onchange="Tuition(this)"> Tution<br>
<div id="tuition_fee" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Tuition Fee</li>
    <input type="radio" name="test1" value="Full"> Full Tuition Fee<br>
    <input type="radio" name="test1" value="Not Full" id="test" onchange="Not_Full(this)"> Not Full Tuition Fee<br>
  </ul>
  <div id="Not_Full" style="display: none;">
    <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>

</div>
<input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="School Supply" id="test" onchange="Supply(this)"> School
<div id="school_supply" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Books</li>
    <li>Uniform</li>
  </ul>
  <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes sir its working.This is what i really want.Maybe your confused of my explanation but your modification is correct.Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help!  :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because each function is called only once when the input is clicked.  When another one is clicked you'll need to hide the ones that are displayed.

Here is a modified example

```js
function expand(element) {
  // collapse all div.expandable
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('expandable'))
    .forEach(function(div) {
      div.style.display = "none";
    });

  // expand the one coresponding to the clicked input
  document.getElementById(element.id.toLowerCase()).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="Allowance" id="Allowance" onchange="expand(this)">
  <label for="Allowance">Allowance</label>
  <div class="expandable" id="allowance" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Food Allowance</li>
      <li>Transportation Allowance</li>
    </ul>
    <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="Tuition Fee" id="Tuition" onchange="expand(this)">
  <label for="Tuition">Tuition</label>
  <div class="expandable" id="tuition" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Tuition Fee</li>
      <input type="radio" name="test1" value="Full"> Full Tuition Fee<br>
      <input type="radio" name="test1" value="Not Full" id="test" onchange="Not_Full(this)"> Not Full Tuition Fee<br>
    </ul>
    <div id="Not_Full" style="display: none;">
      <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li>
  <input type="radio" name="ship_need" value="School Supply" id="School" onchange="expand(this)">
  <label for="School">School</label>
  <div class="expandable" id="school" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li>Books</li>
      <li>Uniform</li>
    </ul>
    <label class="control-label">Money:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</li>
```